# Сортировка vector<pair<int,int>> по second

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

Как отсортировать `vector<pair<int,int>>` по second.
Например, вектор пар является:

`1 - 60
2 - 80
3 - 40
4 - 10`

Нужно получить:

`1 - 10
2 - 40
3 - 60
4 - 80`

Comment: результат, который вам нужно получить - это что угодно, но не результат сортировки

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, я не понел, можно подробнее?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вопрошающий хочет отсортировать пары `int`-ов и приводит пример вроде: `1 - 60`, который, как я понимаю, представляется как `pair{1, 60}` - a в результате у него уже: `3 - 60` - тобишь первое число из пары изменило свое значение. Короче это уже не сортировка (или не только не она)

Answer (score 5):

Написать соответствующий компаратор:

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto a, auto b){ return a.second < b.second; });
```

Если же вы хотите не сортировать, а переупорядочить содержимое пар, как в примере - ну, первое, что приходит на ум - дополнительный вектор, типа

```
vector<pair<int,int>> v { {1,60},{2,80},{3,40},{4,10}};
vector<int> tmp;
for(auto& e: v) tmp.push_back(e.second);
sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i ) v[i].second = tmp[i];
```

Comment: В примере автора происходит что-то странное. Там перемешиваются значения.

Comment: @КириллМалышевЯ прочел вопрос *Как отсортировать `vector<pair<int,int>>` по second* и ответил на него...